# Templates Category - multiple

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In Wordpress how make multiple templates for one category?

E.g. `category-grid/financial-services/`

Comment: Explain exactly what you intend to do. Based on what criteria you want to change the category template?

Comment: I'd like to change display grid/list and oderby A-Z

Comment: Well, still I can't understand you exact problem. You want to apply different template randomly for any category or you want a different template (different than default template) for a specific category?

Comment: 1. I have a category A
2. On the category page should be the button "Change List/Grid".
3. When you click loads a new template.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, you want to change how posts are displayed on category page (list view / grid view), not the entire page template.

Comment: Yes, only on page the category